# Problema na utilização de malloc e realloc

Tags: c, memória

```
int main()
{
    int **matriz;

    f(matriz);

    return 0;
}

void f(int **matriz)
{
    int x, l=1,c=3;

    matriz = (int **) malloc(sizeof (int));
    *matriz = (int *) malloc(3 * sizeof (int));

    printf("Insira o valor de x: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);

    if(x==0)
    {
        c*=2;
        *(matriz) = (int *) realloc(*(matriz),c * sizeof (int));
    }
    else
    {
        l++
        matriz = (int **) realloc(matriz, l* sizeof (int));
        *(matriz) = (int *) malloc(3 * sizeof (int));
    }
}
```

Boas, deixo aqui um exemplo do problema que tenho tido na implementação de malloc e realloc, basicamente eu começo por adicionar uma linha e 3 colunas para inserir certos valores depois na primeira condição eu continuo a inserir na primeira linha, mas na segunda condição eu já quero os valores noutra linha e mais 3 colunas, este tipo de implementação acaba sempre por me dar erro de memória e não sei como encontrar o erro, se alguém pudesse ajudar agradecia.

Comment: Mas a ideia era a função ir pedindo mais valores para inserir os numeros noutras linhas e/ou colunas ? É que só vejo um `scanf` na função. Como está a testar/verificar os valores que obtem?

Comment: basicamente o que voce que fazer

Comment: Provavelmente não expliquei bem o meu problema, o código que coloquei é só um exemplo do código que tenho tido problemas, basicamente é um realloc(): invalid next size e era para saber se esse formato como coloquei em cima tem algum erro, eu basicamente faço 
matriz = (int **) realloc(matriz, l* sizeof (int)); para adicionar nova linha e *(matriz+i) = (int *) malloc(n * sizeof (int)); para adicionar mais colunas, onde poderá estar a vir o erro? Outra coisa que vi é a utilização da inicialização a NULL que eu não uso, é importante essa utilização?

Answer (score 1):

Começo por responder a algumas coisas que colocou nos comentários:

> Outra coisa que vi é a utilização da inicialização a NULL que eu não
>   uso

Em alguns casos torna-se necessário, quando o código testa se determinada coisa vem a `NULL`, noutros serve como boas práticas. No seu exemplo poderia ter declarado a matriz com valor inicial a `NULL`, que inclusivamente resolveria um dos avisos de compilação:

```
int main()
{
    int **matriz = NULL;
    f(matriz); 
    ...
}
```

Ainda que não necessário para a lógica que tem, torna claro qual o valor com que inicia. Quando faz `f(matriz)` está a passar uma copia do ponteiro que tem no main o que faz com que a alocação dentro da função `f` não altere este ponteiro, o que está incorreto.

[Veja esta pergunta que respondi exatamente com o mesmo problema e respetiva solução](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/254564/82711)

> o código que coloquei é só um exemplo do código que tenho tido
>   problemas

O exemplo que colocou é um pouco obscuro, e difícil de decifrar o que era suposto fazer (até porque nem tem um resultado esperado), logo é difícil de ajudar na sua real duvida. Seria melhor ter colocado uma porção do seu código real.

> eu basicamente faço matriz = (int *) realloc(matriz, l sizeof (int));
>   para adicionar nova linha

Se `matriz` é um `int**` e `l` é o novo tamanho, que já foi aumentado de 1 algures, então seria:

```
matriz = (int**) realloc(matriz, l * sizeof (int*));
```

> e *(matriz+i) = (int *) malloc(n * sizeof (int)); para adicionar mais
>   colunas

Assumindo que `n` é o numero de colunas de cada linha está certo, mas mais simples seria fazer:

```
matriz[i] = (int *) malloc(n * sizeof (int));
```

**Passando ao código em si**

Quando faz:

```
*matriz = (int *) malloc(3 * sizeof (int));
```

Embora funcione é um pouco estranho, e mais à frente o mesmo principio é utilizado de forma incorreta. Nesta instrução pretende atribuir à primeira linha um array de `3` inteiros, que seriam as colunas. Torne isso mais claro fazendo:

```
matriz[0] = (int *) malloc(3 * sizeof (int));
```

Por isso o `realloc` que está certo é o penúltimo :

```
else
{
    l++
    //-^ falta ;

    matriz = (int **) realloc(matriz, l* sizeof (int)); //<--correto
    *(matriz) = (int *) malloc(3 * sizeof (int)); //<--incorreto
}
```

Este ultimo deveria ser:

```
matriz[l-1] = (int *) malloc(3 * sizeof (int));
```

Ou se quiser utilizar notação de ponteiros, como estava a utilizar:

```
*(matriz+l-1)  = (int *) malloc(3 * sizeof (int));
```

**Exemplo distinto com criação dinâmica de linhas e colunas**

Segue um exemplo diferente com criação dinâmica de linhas e colunas de uma matriz e com realocação para mais linhas, como estava a tentar fazer. Fiz um exemplo diferente para ser mais intuitivo e claro, e apenas se focar na parte que pretende saber.

```
int main()
{
    int linhas = 2, colunas = 5, i;
    int **matriz = (int **) malloc(sizeof (int*) * linhas); //cria as linhas

    //cria as colunas em cada linha
    for (i = 0; i < linhas; ++i){
        matriz[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof (int) * colunas);
    }

    //coloca alguns valores e mostra
    matriz[0][1] = 10; 
    matriz[1][3] = 10;
    mostrarMatriz(matriz, linhas, colunas);

    //cria uma nova linha
    matriz = (int**) realloc(matriz, sizeof(int*) * ++linhas);

    //cria as colunas para essa nova linha
    matriz[linhas-1] = (int*)malloc(sizeof (int) * colunas);

    //atribui um valor na nova linha e volta a mostrar o resultado
    matriz[linhas-1][0] = 5;
    mostrarMatriz(matriz, linhas, colunas);

    return 0;
}
```

[Veja o resultado no Ideone](https://ideone.com/lnZJhI)

Note que deixei valores não inicializados na matriz para simplificar o código. No *Ideone* estão a aparecer como zeros, mas não é garantido que assim o seja, logo seria de todo boa prática atribuir valores em toda a matriz.

Answer (score 0):

aqui um exemplo utilizando colunas e linhas
**mapa.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "fogefoge.h"

char** mapa;
int linhas;
int colunas;

void liberamapa(){
    for (int i = 0; i < linhas; ++i)
    {
        free(mapa[i]);
    }
    free(mapa);
}
void alocamapa(){
    mapa = malloc(sizeof(char*) * linhas);
    for (int i = 0; i < linhas; ++i)
    {       
        mapa[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (colunas +1));
    }
}
void lemapa(){
        FILE* f;

    f = fopen("mapa.txt", "r");
    if(f == 0) {
        printf("Erro na leitura do mapa");
        exit(1);
    }

    fscanf(f, "%d %d", &linhas, &colunas);
    alocamapa();

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        fscanf(f, "%s", mapa[i]);
    }
    fclose(f);
}
int main() {

    lemapa();


    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", mapa[i]);
    }

    liberamapa();

}

matriz = malloc(sizeof(int*)* linhas);
for (int i = 0; i < linhas; ++i)
{       
    matriz[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * colunas);
}
```

**arquivo.h**

```
void liberamapa();
void alocamapa();
void lemapa();
```

**mapa**

```
|--------|
|...|..-.|
|..-|.@..|
|......-.|
|--------|
```

Answer (score 0):

O código postado tem vários problemas, que explico abaixo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void f(int **matriz);

int main()
{
  int **matriz;

  // nao faz sentido passar um ponteiro nao inicializado para uma funcao!
  f(matriz);
  return 0;
}

void f(int **matriz)
{
  int x, l = 1, c = 3;

  // matriz = (int **) malloc(sizeof (int)); // <-------- ERRO
  matriz = (int **) malloc(sizeof (int*));   // tem que alocar "int*", nao "int"
  // neste ponto matriz[0] existe, mas aponta para "lixo"

  *matriz = (int *) malloc(3 * sizeof (int));
  // neste ponto existem
  // matriz[0][0]
  // matriz[0][1]
  // matriz[0][2]
  // mas nao sabemos qual seu conteudo

  printf("Insira o valor de x: ");
  scanf("%d", &x);

  if (x == 0)
  {
    c *= 2;
    *(matriz) = (int *) realloc(*(matriz),c * sizeof (int));
    // neste ponto existem
    // matriz[0][0]
    // matriz[0][1]
    // matriz[0][2]
    // matriz[0][3]
    // matriz[0][4]
    // matriz[0][5]
    // mas nao sabemos qual seu conteudo
  }
  else
  {
    // l++ // <------------------------ ERRO faltando ;
    l++;
    matriz = (int **) realloc(matriz, l* sizeof (int));
    // neste ponto existem
    // matriz[0][0]
    // matriz[0][1]
    // matriz[0][2]
    // matriz[1]    <--- novo ponteiro
    // mas nao sabemos qual seu conteudo

    // *(matriz) = (int *) malloc(3 * sizeof (int));
    // esta' realocando *matriz, que e' equivalente a matriz[0], mas como esta'
    // realocando para um mesmo tamanho, provavelmente nada vai ser realocado!

    // o correto é fazer o malloc de *(matriz+1), equivalente a matriz[1]
    *(matriz+1) = (int *) malloc(3 * sizeof (int));
    // neste ponto existem
    // matriz[0][0]
    // matriz[0][1]
    // matriz[0][2]
    // matriz[1][0]
    // matriz[1][1]
    // matriz[0][2]
    // mas nao sabemos qual seu conteudo
  }
}
```