# Como modificar matriz dinâmica?

Tags: c++

Estou com problemas para modificar uma matriz dinâmica já criada. O exemplo a seguir retrata o meu problema. Nesse exemplo o programa compila mas dá erro de execução ( não aparece nada e mostra a caixa de dialogo dizendo que o programa parou de funcionar).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

void Alocar(int **m,int rows,int cols){

    m = (int **)malloc((rows)*sizeof(int*));

    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
         m[i] = (int *)malloc(cols*sizeof(int));   
    }

}

void Modificar(int **m,int rows,int cols){


     for(int i=0; i<rows ;i++)
     {
        for(int j=0; j<cols ; j++)
        {

          m[i][j]= 0;
        }
     }
     cout << " Matriz zerada" << endl;
      for(int i=0; i<rows ;i++)
     {
        for(int j=0; j<cols ; j++)
        {

          cout << m[i][j]<< " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
     }

}

int main()
{
     int **M;

     Alocar(M,100,100);

     Modificar(M,100,100);

    return 0;

}
```

Alguém sabe por que esta ocorrendo esse tipo de problema?

Comment: Em C+= não deve fazer desta forma, deve usar um `vector` ou outra estrutura. Está programa em C no C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema no código apresentado vem na função `Alocar`. Quando faz `m = ...` dentro da função `Alocar` está a alterar uma copia do ponteiro que está no `main` o que faz com que o do `main` continue sem ser inicializado.

Pode resolver este problema de algumas formas:

- Devolvendo o novo ponteiro como retorno

  ```
  int** Alocar(int **m,int rows,int cols) {  
  //^---tipo de retorno para int**

      m = (int **)malloc((rows)*sizeof(int*));

      for(int i=0; i<rows; i++) {
          m[i] = (int *)malloc(cols*sizeof(int));
      }

      return m; //retorna aqui
  }

  int main() {
      int **M = Alocar(M,100,100); //guarda o retornado em m
      Modificar(M,100,100);

      return 0;
  }
  ```

  [Exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/jnHerM)

  <sup>Alterei a quantidade para 10 para ser mais facil de se ver</sup>
- Passando o endereço da matriz à função:

  ```
  void Alocar(int ***m,int rows,int cols) {
      //----------^ agora int***

      *m = (int **)malloc((rows)*sizeof(int*)); //com * para ser o valor apontado

      for(int i=0; i<rows; i++) {
          (*m)[i] = (int *)malloc(cols*sizeof(int)); //com * tambem
      }
  }

  int main() {
      int **M;

      Alocar(&M,100,100); //passa o endereço agora
      Modificar(M,100,100);

      return 0;

  }
  ```

  [Exemplo também no Ideone](https://ideone.com/u8EoqL)
- Exclusivamente em C++ tem até a idiomática passagem por referência que simplifica ainda mais. O compilador internamente acaba por tratar como se fosse um ponteiro para o original:

  ```
  void Alocar(int **&m,int rows,int cols) {
      //------------^ referencia aqui o resto igual ao que tinha originalmente
      m = (int **)malloc((rows)*sizeof(int*));

      for(int i=0; i<rows; i++) {
          m[i] = (int *)malloc(cols*sizeof(int));
      }
  }

  int main() { //o main mantem-se igual
      int **M;

      Alocar(M,100,100);
      Modificar(M,100,100);

      return 0;
  }
  ```

  [Exemplo final no Ideone](https://ideone.com/56rTSZ)

Comment: Perfeito. Obrigado pela reposta com várias alternativas.